# My siege engineers are too scared to do their job. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Note I'm playing a succession game using version 40d.

So I've set up a [Maze of Death](http://aslum.net/dwarffortress/toscaredtoballista.png) with a nearly a score of ballista at the ready to fill invaders with pointy death. Unfortunatly my ballista operators run up to fire the ballista, realize they're about to shoot some goblins and flee. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that they have line of sight to the goblins. Siege Engineers are just like any other dwarf civilian, and will flee from danger.

Unless you're lucky enough to acquire a forgotten beast syndrome that causes your dwarves eyes to rot, you're going to have to engineer a setup where your dwarves won't see their targets. (As unintuitive as that sounds, just roll with it. They're dwarves.)

In practice, this just means your ballista are too close to your maze of death. The [wiki suggests](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php?title=Siege_engine#Using_Siege_Engines_.28simple.29) that moving the siege engines back 10 squares should be sufficient.

Comment: Sounds good... of course it doesn't do much good this siege as I doubt my workers will get close enough to *move* the Ballista until I've got the goblins cleaned up...

Comment: @aslum - You're right about not being able to move the ballista, but I believe every square of a ballista can be shot through, so you can simply set up more ballista behind your initial lines, if you have spares.

Comment: @aslum - There will be more sieges. There's *always* more sieges.

Comment: Further down (http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Ballista#Using_Siege_Engines_.28advanced.29) the wiki suggests 20 squares.  But in any case, yeah, setting up siege engines is a real hassle sometimes.